# Check if array of size n contains 0 to n-1

Tags: arrays, sorting

Here's the question I need to answer:
My program gets an array of the size n, that contains numbers from 0 to n-1. You can assume that we don't get numbers below 0 or numbers above n-1.

I need to check if the array contains ALL the numbers between 0 to n-1, and return 1 if it does. 0 otherwise.

examples:

Array of the size 5: `4,1,0,3,2` return 1.

Array of the size 5: `4,1,0,3,1` return 0 (2 isn't in the array)

What I tried to do:

```
    int Ex4_bonus() //sort a using a single for loop, then iterate through it with another for loop to look 
{              // for a spot that doesnt equal the value inside it.
    int i,n,boolean=1,temp=0;
    int* a;
    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=input_array_dyn(a,n);
    printf("Enter numbers from 0-%d\n",n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=i)
        {
            temp=a[a[i]];
            a[a[i]]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]!=i)
            boolean=0;
    printf("%d\n",boolean);
    return boolean;
    free(a);
}
```

but it's not working for some arrays. Where did I go wrong and is there a better way? You are not allowed to use another array, and the program must run in O(n).

Comment: You could sort the array and run through it, checking that each item's value is equal to it's index.

Comment: That's what my code does. But for some reason it's not working on some arrays.

Comment: If you really want O(n) you obviously can't run through the array more than once.

Comment: Why not use [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) for sorting?

Comment: qsort isn't O(n) its nlogn

Comment: So you can't even sort it if you wanna do O(n). I think using a set would be cheaper. It would be O(n log n), cause set operations are log n.  I'm not sure it's possible in O(n) time. I don't know if a set is an array in the eyes of the assignment.

Comment: Calculate the sum of `2**a[i]`. If it's not equal to `(2**n)-1` then you're missing an element.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the sum of `2**a[i]`. If it's not equal to `(2**n)-1` then you're missing an element.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean arrayCheck(int[] ints) {
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
  while (i != ints[i]) {
    int currPosVal = ints[i];
    if (currPosVal <= i || currPosVal >= ints.length) {
      return false;
    }
    int temp = ints[currPosVal];
    if (currPosVal == temp) {
      return false;
    }
    ints[i] = temp;
    ints[currPosVal] = currPosVal;
  }
}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the characteristic of xor operation.

C++ :

```
bool solve(vector<int>& arr){
    int xor = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
        xor ^= i;

    for (int  v: arr)
        xor ^= v;

    return xor == 0;
}
```

or:

```
bool solve(vector<int>& arr){
    int xor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        xor ^= i^arr[i];

    return xor == 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this fails for the vector `{1,1,1,1,1}`